# 'require is not defined' error when attempting to use chartjs in javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, chart.js

I'm neew to node and javascript. I am trying to incorporate chartjs into my project. I have a  javascript file linked to an html file.  The two files are shown below:

charts.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Charts</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="paragraph">This will be the Charts page.</p>

  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="js/charts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

charts.js:

```
//jshint esversion:6

var chart = require('chart.js'); //what's going on here??

var paragraph = document.querySelector("#paragraph");

//set click event listener
paragraph.addEventListener("click", changeMessage);

function changeMessage() {
  paragraph.textContent = "clicked!";
  console.log(paragraph.textContent);
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is in the way I'm importing the chart.js dependency. The line `var chart = require('chart.js');` is what I am attempting, but when rendering the html page, I see a console error claiming: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".  Removing thatt line entirely makes the program complain about it not recognizing the `Chart` object.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: `what's going on here` - require is a nodejs thing (yeah, there is a `require` library, but that probably isn't going to help) - instead, rad how to use chart.js in the ["documentation"](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)

Comment: `require` is specific to NodeJS. If you're running this in the browser, you can't (and shouldn't be trying to) use it. Depending on how modern the library is, you need to either include a reference to it in its own `script` tag or use `import` instead. (Most likely the first one, as not many libraries support `import` yet.)

Comment: easiest solution `<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js"></script>` in the `<head>` ... or download `chart.js` to your server and adjust `src=` as appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/) library imports. Just copy the link [at the Chart.js-site](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js) and put it in your html-file.

```
<head>
  <title>Charts</title>  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on node you need to npm install require.js. If you are not on node you can use ES6 Import.